# how to separate retrieved data from mysql using colon in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I am retrieving data from mysql using shell script and i want to add colon in retrieved data to separate help me how to do that?

```
data=$(mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME -se "SELECT * FROM $TABLE WHERE fname='$fname' AND lname='$lname';") 

echo "$data"

OUTPUT 

Alex  George  990070070 alex.george@gmail.com

Desired OUTPUT

Alex George : 990070070 : alex.george@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working for me. I hope working for you also.

```
data=$(mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME -se "SELECT * FROM $TABLE WHERE fname='$fname' AND lname='$lname';" | tr '\t' ':' | sed -e 's/\([^[:blank:]]\):\([^[:blank:]]\)/\1 : \2/g')
```

Answer (score 1):

Following may help you on same.

```
your_command | sed 's/ +/ : /g'
```

***OR***

```
your_command | sed 's/[[:blank:]]+/ : /g'
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix:

```
data="$(mysql --user=$DB_USER \
              --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME \
              --batch \
              -se "SELECT * FROM $TABLE WHERE fname='$fname' AND lname='$lname';" | sed -e 's/\t/\t:\t/')"
```

[`--batch`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_batch): Print results using tab as the column separator

`sed -e 's/\t/\t:\t/'`: Turns `tabs` into `tab` + `:` + `tab`

Or:

`sed -e 's/\t/ : /'`: If you want *blanks*

Comment: Alex:George:990070070:alex.george@gmail.com     its printing like this but there is not tab between data

Comment: See my ed answer